# self-hosted Owncloud slow when accessing server using external IP/domain name whilst still on home network

Tags: docker, owncloud

I'm running a OwnCloud instance using Docker on a server running on my home network. When I access this server using its internal IP (using NAT) its fast (as you would expect). However, if I try to access it using my external IP whilst still on my home network, its REALLY slow, using at least 2.5 minutes to load the login-screen. When trying to access the server from another network (for example work, or using 4G) its acting normal.

Port 80 and 443 is forwarded to the correct internal IP.

I'm using a jelly bean TP-link router.

Comment: When using the external IP from the internal LAN, your packets travel thru your router, and this may be solved badly within this specific device.

Comment: Does this behaviour also apply to to other devices in your network?